# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\server.js' in Node server for Meanjs

Tags: node.js, gulp, meanjs, nodemon

I have git cloned meanjs into a folder in D: drive as shown below and ran the command npm start to start the node server.

```
admin@admin-PC MINGW32 /d/Udemy Angular 1 projects/Project5/jobfinder (master)
$ npm start

> meanjs@0.5.0 start D:\Udemy Angular 1 projects\Project5\jobfinder
> gulp

[23:41:30] Using gulpfile D:\Udemy Angular 1 projects\Project5\jobfinder\gulpfile.js
```

....and got the below error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
[23:58:35] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

After that, just to give it a try I copied the server.js from the current directory to C:\ and issued 'npm start' command at git bash from the same directory and the error changed to below.

```
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
module.js:457
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './config/lib/app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\server.js:6:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
[23:41:52] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can anyone please help me understand why is Node looking for server.js and other resources at C:\ instead of the current directory? Is there anything very simple I am missing out (though I find it quite strange !). Btw sorry for posting the git bash errors as code since I did not have enough reputations to post more than one image link.

Cheers!

**Adding my research ....**

Invoking 'npm start' command in meanjs directory hits the file gulpfile.js. Looking into the file, I saw that a gulp task (nodemon) was initiated as below and the script property of the return object was set to 'server.js'.

**Code from gulpfile.js.**

```
gulp.task('nodemon', function () {

  var nodeVersions = process.versions;
  var debugArgument = '--debug';
  switch (nodeVersions.node.substr(0, 1)) {
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    debugArgument = '--debug';
    break;
    case '7':
      debugArgument = '--inspect';
      break;
  }
  console.log('nodemon task'); // checking execution of the callback
  return plugins.nodemon({
    script: 'server.js',
    nodeArgs: [debugArgument],
    ext: 'js,html',
    verbose: true,
    watch: _.union(defaultAssets.server.views, defaultAssets.server.allJS, defaultAssets.server.config)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above problem was solved by deleting the Autorun string in the registry at the below path.

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor".

The autorun string was set to C: and as a result Nodemon recognised C: as the root instead of the current directory in Gitbash or command prompt.